# crontab module not working

Tags: python, cron

I am running a python script from another python script via python crontab module.It's not returning any thing and the job is also not executing.

caller.py

```
from crontab import CronTab
import os

cron    = CronTab()
job  = cron.new(command='job1.py')
job.minute.during(1,5).every(1)
job.enable()
if job.is_valid():
    print True
```

job1.py

```
    for i in range(0,2,1):
        f=open("abc%d.txt" %i,"w")
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Write crontab to system using:

> cron.write()

add this in caller.py

This code is working:
caller.py

```
from crontab import CronTab
import os
cron    = CronTab(user='root')
job  = cron.new(command='/usr/bin/python /home/you/script/job1.py')
job.minute.during(1,5).every(1)
job.enable()
if job.is_valid():
    print True
cron.write()
```

job1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
os.chdir("/home/you/script")
for i in range(0,2,1):
   f=open("abc%d.txt" %i,"w")
   f.close()
```

Comment: You have to change the command to /usr/bin/python job1.py
and if you use the /home path put this in job1.py:
import os
os.chdir("/home/path/to/your/script")

You can also check il the cron is saved with the command crontab -l
And check in the syslog (/var/log/syslog)